# Как можно задать схему бизнес-процесса в jira для отдельного компонента?

Tags: jira

Есть 4 компонента проекта:

- Дизайн
- Верстка
- Фронтенд
- Бекенд

Можно ли задать для каждого отдельно свою схему бизнес-процесса?

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Но можно создать 4 типа задач и для каждой задачи назначить свой бизнес-процесс